# How can I had multiple chekbox on account creation on Prestashop 1.6

Tags: forms, prestashop-1.6, account, checkboxlist

I would like to know more about my customers during their registration on my website. For this I just want to add on the account creation 5 checkoxes (he can choose more than one checkbox) and save it in the database and in personnal information in the account. Easy for me to add the checkboxes in the form, but I have no idea to do the rest.

I already add the checkboxes in the code, but I don't know what I need to change after. I modified only the authentication.tpl file.

This is my code to add the checkboxes in the form :

```
<p class="textarea">
    <label for="other">{l s='Je suis :'}</label>
    <div id="other_info">
    <input class="checkboxx" type="checkbox" value="{if isset($smarty.post.other)}{$smarty.post.other}{/if}" id="other" name="Céréalier"> 
            <span class="cerealier">Céréalier</span>
    <input class="checkboxx" type="checkbox" value="{if isset($smarty.post.other)}{$smarty.post.other}{/if}" id="other" name="Éleveur"> 
            <span class="eleveur">Éleveur</span>
    <input class="checkboxx" type="checkbox" value="{if isset($smarty.post.other)}{$smarty.post.other}{/if}" id="other" name="Viticulteur"> 
            <span class="viticulteur">Viticulteur</span>
    <input class="checkboxx" type="checkbox" value="{if isset($smarty.post.other)}{$smarty.post.other}{/if}" id="other" name="Revendeur"> 
            <span class="revendeur">Revendeur</span>
    <input class="checkboxx" type="checkbox" value="{if isset($smarty.post.other)}{$smarty.post.other}{/if}" id="other" name="Autre"> 
            <span class="autre">Autre</span><br>
    </div>
</p>
```

I would like someone to help to realise this implemation on account creation with my multiple checkboxes.

This is my method processSubmitAccount() :

```
protected function processSubmitAccount()
    {
        Hook::exec('actionBeforeSubmitAccount');
        $this->create_account = true;
        if (Tools::isSubmit('submitAccount')) {
            $this->context->smarty->assign('email_create', 1);
        }
        // New Guest customer
        if (!Tools::getValue('is_new_customer', 1) && !Configuration::get('PS_GUEST_CHECKOUT_ENABLED')) {
            $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('You cannot create a guest account.');
        }
        if (!Tools::getValue('is_new_customer', 1)) {
            $_POST['passwd'] = md5(time()._COOKIE_KEY_);
        }
        if ($guest_email = Tools::getValue('guest_email')) {
            $_POST['email'] = $guest_email;
        }
        // Checked the user address in case he changed his email address
        if (Validate::isEmail($email = Tools::getValue('email')) && !empty($email)) {
            if (Customer::customerExists($email)) {
                $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('An account using this email address has already been registered.', false);
            }
        }
        // Preparing customer
        $customer = new Customer();
        $other = Tools::getValue('other');
        var_dump($other);
        exit;
        $customer->other = $other;
        $lastnameAddress = Tools::getValue('lastname');
        $firstnameAddress = Tools::getValue('firstname');
        $_POST['lastname'] = Tools::getValue('customer_lastname', $lastnameAddress);
        $_POST['firstname'] = Tools::getValue('customer_firstname', $firstnameAddress);
        $addresses_types = array('address');
        if (!Configuration::get('PS_ORDER_PROCESS_TYPE') && Configuration::get('PS_GUEST_CHECKOUT_ENABLED') && Tools::getValue('invoice_address')) {
            $addresses_types[] = 'address_invoice';
        }

        $error_phone = false;
        if (Configuration::get('PS_ONE_PHONE_AT_LEAST')) {
            if (Tools::isSubmit('submitGuestAccount') || !Tools::getValue('is_new_customer')) {
                if (!Tools::getValue('phone') && !Tools::getValue('phone_mobile')) {
                    $error_phone = true;
                }
            } elseif (((Configuration::get('PS_REGISTRATION_PROCESS_TYPE') && Configuration::get('PS_ORDER_PROCESS_TYPE'))
                    || (Configuration::get('PS_ORDER_PROCESS_TYPE') && !Tools::getValue('email_create'))
                    || (Configuration::get('PS_REGISTRATION_PROCESS_TYPE') && Tools::getValue('email_create')))
                    && (!Tools::getValue('phone') && !Tools::getValue('phone_mobile'))) {
                $error_phone = true;
            }
        }

        if ($error_phone) {
            $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('You must register at least one phone number.');
        }

        $this->errors = array_unique(array_merge($this->errors, $customer->validateController()));

        // Check the requires fields which are settings in the BO
        $this->errors = $this->errors + $customer->validateFieldsRequiredDatabase();

        if (!Configuration::get('PS_REGISTRATION_PROCESS_TYPE') && !$this->ajax && !Tools::isSubmit('submitGuestAccount')) {
            if (!count($this->errors)) {

                $this->processCustomerNewsletter($customer);

                $customer->firstname = Tools::ucwords($customer->firstname);
                $customer->birthday = (empty($_POST['years']) ? '' : (int)Tools::getValue('years').'-'.(int)Tools::getValue('months').'-'.(int)Tools::getValue('days'));
                if (!Validate::isBirthDate($customer->birthday)) {
                    $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('Invalid date of birth.');
                }

                // New Guest customer
                $customer->is_guest = (Tools::isSubmit('is_new_customer') ? !Tools::getValue('is_new_customer', 1) : 0);
                $customer->active = 1;

                if (!count($this->errors)) {
                    if ($customer->add()) {
                        if (!$customer->is_guest) {
                            if (!$this->sendConfirmationMail($customer)) {
                                $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('The email cannot be sent.');
                            }
                        }

                        $this->updateContext($customer);

                        $this->context->cart->update();
                        Hook::exec('actionCustomerAccountAdd', array(
                                '_POST' => $_POST,
                                'newCustomer' => $customer
                            ));
                        if ($this->ajax) {
                            $return = array(
                                'hasError' => !empty($this->errors),
                                'errors' => $this->errors,
                                'isSaved' => true,
                                'id_customer' => (int)$this->context->cookie->id_customer,
                                'id_address_delivery' => $this->context->cart->id_address_delivery,
                                'id_address_invoice' => $this->context->cart->id_address_invoice,
                                'token' => Tools::getToken(false)
                            );
                            $this->ajaxDie(Tools::jsonEncode($return));
                        }

                        if (($back = Tools::getValue('back')) && $back == Tools::secureReferrer($back)) {
                            Tools::redirect(html_entity_decode($back));
                        }

                        // redirection: if cart is not empty : redirection to the cart
                        if (count($this->context->cart->getProducts(true)) > 0) {
                            $multi = (int)Tools::getValue('multi-shipping');
                            Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order'.($multi ? '&multi-shipping='.$multi : ''));
                        }
                        // else : redirection to the account
                        else {
                            Tools::redirect('index.php?controller='.(($this->authRedirection !== false) ? urlencode($this->authRedirection) : 'my-account'));
                        }
                    } else {
                        $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('An error occurred while creating your account.');
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            // if registration type is in one step, we save the address

            $_POST['lastname'] = $lastnameAddress;
            $_POST['firstname'] = $firstnameAddress;
            $post_back = $_POST;
            // Preparing addresses
            foreach ($addresses_types as $addresses_type) {
                $$addresses_type = new Address();
                $$addresses_type->id_customer = 1;

                if ($addresses_type == 'address_invoice') {
                    foreach ($_POST as $key => &$post) {
                        if ($tmp = Tools::getValue($key.'_invoice')) {
                            $post = $tmp;
                        }
                    }
                }

                $this->errors = array_unique(array_merge($this->errors, $$addresses_type->validateController()));
                if ($addresses_type == 'address_invoice') {
                    $_POST = $post_back;
                }

                if (!($country = new Country($$addresses_type->id_country)) || !Validate::isLoadedObject($country)) {
                    $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('Country cannot be loaded with address->id_country');
                }

                if (!$country->active) {
                    $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('This country is not active.');
                }

                $postcode = $$addresses_type->postcode;
                /* Check zip code format */
                if ($country->zip_code_format && !$country->checkZipCode($postcode)) {
                    $this->errors[] = sprintf(Tools::displayError('The Zip/Postal code you\'ve entered is invalid. It must follow this format: %s'), str_replace('C', $country->iso_code, str_replace('N', '0', str_replace('L', 'A', $country->zip_code_format))));
                } elseif (empty($postcode) && $country->need_zip_code) {
                    $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('A Zip / Postal code is required.');
                } elseif ($postcode && !Validate::isPostCode($postcode)) {
                    $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('The Zip / Postal code is invalid.');
                }

                if ($country->need_identification_number && (!Tools::getValue('dni') || !Validate::isDniLite(Tools::getValue('dni')))) {
                    $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('The identification number is incorrect or has already been used.');
                } elseif (!$country->need_identification_number) {
                    $$addresses_type->dni = null;
                }

                if (Tools::isSubmit('submitAccount') || Tools::isSubmit('submitGuestAccount')) {
                    if (!($country = new Country($$addresses_type->id_country, Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT'))) || !Validate::isLoadedObject($country)) {
                        $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('Country is invalid');
                    }
                }
                $contains_state = isset($country) && is_object($country) ? (int)$country->contains_states: 0;
                $id_state = isset($$addresses_type) && is_object($$addresses_type) ? (int)$$addresses_type->id_state: 0;
                if ((Tools::isSubmit('submitAccount') || Tools::isSubmit('submitGuestAccount')) && $contains_state && !$id_state) {
                    $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('This country requires you to choose a State.');
                }
            }
        }

        if (!@checkdate(Tools::getValue('months'), Tools::getValue('days'), Tools::getValue('years')) && !(Tools::getValue('months') == '' && Tools::getValue('days') == '' && Tools::getValue('years') == '')) {
            $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('Invalid date of birth');
        }

        if (!count($this->errors)) {
            if (Customer::customerExists(Tools::getValue('email'))) {
                $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('An account using this email address has already been registered. Please enter a valid password or request a new one. ', false);
            }

            $this->processCustomerNewsletter($customer);

            $customer->birthday = (empty($_POST['years']) ? '' : (int)Tools::getValue('years').'-'.(int)Tools::getValue('months').'-'.(int)Tools::getValue('days'));
            if (!Validate::isBirthDate($customer->birthday)) {
                $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('Invalid date of birth');
            }

            if (!count($this->errors)) {
                $customer->active = 1;
                // New Guest customer
                if (Tools::isSubmit('is_new_customer')) {
                    $customer->is_guest = !Tools::getValue('is_new_customer', 1);
                } else {
                    $customer->is_guest = 0;
                }
                if (!$customer->add()) {
                    $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('An error occurred while creating your account.');
                } else {
                    foreach ($addresses_types as $addresses_type) {
                        $$addresses_type->id_customer = (int)$customer->id;
                        if ($addresses_type == 'address_invoice') {
                            foreach ($_POST as $key => &$post) {
                                if ($tmp = Tools::getValue($key.'_invoice')) {
                                    $post = $tmp;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        $this->errors = array_unique(array_merge($this->errors, $$addresses_type->validateController()));
                        if ($addresses_type == 'address_invoice') {
                            $_POST = $post_back;
                        }
                        if (!count($this->errors) && (Configuration::get('PS_REGISTRATION_PROCESS_TYPE') || $this->ajax || Tools::isSubmit('submitGuestAccount')) && !$$addresses_type->add()) {
                            $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('An error occurred while creating your address.');
                        }
                    }
                    if (!count($this->errors)) {
                        if (!$customer->is_guest) {
                            $this->context->customer = $customer;
                            $customer->cleanGroups();
                            // we add the guest customer in the default customer group
                            $customer->addGroups(array((int)Configuration::get('PS_CUSTOMER_GROUP')));
                            if (!$this->sendConfirmationMail($customer)) {
                                $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('The email cannot be sent.');
                            }
                        } else {
                            $customer->cleanGroups();
                            // we add the guest customer in the guest customer group
                            $customer->addGroups(array((int)Configuration::get('PS_GUEST_GROUP')));
                        }
                        $this->updateContext($customer);
                        $this->context->cart->id_address_delivery = (int)Address::getFirstCustomerAddressId((int)$customer->id);
                        $this->context->cart->id_address_invoice = (int)Address::getFirstCustomerAddressId((int)$customer->id);
                        if (isset($address_invoice) && Validate::isLoadedObject($address_invoice)) {
                            $this->context->cart->id_address_invoice = (int)$address_invoice->id;
                        }

                        if ($this->ajax && Configuration::get('PS_ORDER_PROCESS_TYPE')) {
                            $delivery_option = array((int)$this->context->cart->id_address_delivery => (int)$this->context->cart->id_carrier.',');
                            $this->context->cart->setDeliveryOption($delivery_option);
                        }

                        // If a logged guest logs in as a customer, the cart secure key was already set and needs to be updated
                        $this->context->cart->update();

                        // Avoid articles without delivery address on the cart
                        $this->context->cart->autosetProductAddress();

                        Hook::exec('actionCustomerAccountAdd', array(
                                '_POST' => $_POST,
                                'newCustomer' => $customer
                            ));
                        if ($this->ajax) {
                            $return = array(
                                'hasError' => !empty($this->errors),
                                'errors' => $this->errors,
                                'isSaved' => true,
                                'id_customer' => (int)$this->context->cookie->id_customer,
                                'id_address_delivery' => $this->context->cart->id_address_delivery,
                                'id_address_invoice' => $this->context->cart->id_address_invoice,
                                'token' => Tools::getToken(false)
                            );
                            $this->ajaxDie(Tools::jsonEncode($return));
                        }
                        // if registration type is in two steps, we redirect to register address
                        if (!Configuration::get('PS_REGISTRATION_PROCESS_TYPE') && !$this->ajax && !Tools::isSubmit('submitGuestAccount')) {
                            Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=address');
                        }

                        if (($back = Tools::getValue('back')) && $back == Tools::secureReferrer($back)) {
                            Tools::redirect(html_entity_decode($back));
                        }

                        // redirection: if cart is not empty : redirection to the cart
                        if (count($this->context->cart->getProducts(true)) > 0) {
                            Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order'.($multi = (int)Tools::getValue('multi-shipping') ? '&multi-shipping='.$multi : ''));
                        }
                        // else : redirection to the account
                        else {
                            Tools::redirect('index.php?controller='.(($this->authRedirection !== false) ? urlencode($this->authRedirection) : 'my-account'));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (count($this->errors)) {
            //for retro compatibility to display guest account creation form on authentication page
            if (Tools::getValue('submitGuestAccount')) {
                $_GET['display_guest_checkout'] = 1;
            }

            if (!Tools::getValue('is_new_customer')) {
                unset($_POST['passwd']);
            }
            if ($this->ajax) {
                $return = array(
                    'hasError' => !empty($this->errors),
                    'errors' => $this->errors,
                    'isSaved' => false,
                    'id_customer' => 0
                );
                $this->ajaxDie(Tools::jsonEncode($return));
            }
            $this->context->smarty->assign('account_error', $this->errors);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to know that checkbox need same name but different values. so i think you more need radio buttons than checkboxes.

anyway, to add field to registration form, you need just some modifications (backup bdd and code first) :

1. modify HTML
2. modify Database structure
3. modify PHP

1) Template

```
    <p class="textarea">
<label for="typeagri">{l s='Je suis :'}</label>
<div id="typeagri_info">
<span class="cerealier">Céréalier</span>
<input class="checkboxx" type="checkbox" value="Céréalier" id="typeagri1" name="typeagri[]">
<span class="eleveur">Éleveur</span>
<input class="checkboxx" type="checkbox" value="Éleveur" id="typeagri2" name="typeagri[]">
<span class="viticulteur">Viticulteur</span>
<input class="checkboxx" type="checkbox" value="Viticulteur" id="typeagri3" name="typeagri[]"> 
<span class="revendeur">Revendeur</span>
<input class="checkboxx" type="checkbox" value="Revendeur" id="typeagri4" name="typeagri[]"> 
<span class="autre">Autre</span>
<input class="checkboxx" type="checkbox" value="Autre" id="typeagri5" name="typeagri[]">
</div>
</p>
```

2) Database change (execute SQL in phpmyadmin)

```
ALTER TABLE ps_customer 
ADD COLUMN typeagri VARCHAR(250)
```

3) PHP changes

in /controllers/front/AuthController.php

find "// if registration type is in one step, we save the address" 
and after add that code :

```
$typeagris ='';
foreach(Tools::getValue('typeagri') as $t) { 

            $typeagris .= $t.','; 

} 

$customer->typeagri = $typeagris;
```

in /classes/Customer.php

find "public $firstname;"  and after add that code :

```
/** @var string typeagri */
public $typeagri;
```

find "'passwd' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isPasswd', 'required' => true, 'size' => 32),"  and after add that code :

```
'typeagri' =>  array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING),
```

empty cache and test your modifications.

And for the identity form :

in indentity.tpl

After :

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="website">{l s='Website'}</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="website" name="website" value="{if isset($smarty.post.website)}{$smarty.post.website}{/if}" />
        </div>
```

add :

```
<div class="form-group">    
<p class="textarea">
<label for="typeagri">{l s='Je suis :'}</label>
<!--
        {assign var="typeagris" value=","|explode:$smarty.post.typeagri} 
        {section name=i loop=$typeagris} 
        {$typeagris[i]}<br>
        {/section}
--> 
<div id="typeagri_info">
<input {if $smarty.post.typeagri|stristr:"alier"} checked=checked{/if} class="checkboxx" type="checkbox" value="Céréalier" id="typeagri1" name="typeagri[]"> <span class="cerealier">Céréalier</span>
<input {if $smarty.post.typeagri|stristr:"leveur"} checked=checked{/if} class="checkboxx" type="checkbox" value="Éleveur" id="typeagri2" name="typeagri[]"> <span class="eleveur">Éleveur</span>
<input {if $smarty.post.typeagri|stristr:"iticulteur"} checked=checked{/if} class="checkboxx" type="checkbox" value="Viticulteur" id="typeagri3" name="typeagri[]"> <span class="viticulteur">Viticulteur</span>
<input {if $smarty.post.typeagri|stristr:"evendeur"} checked=checked{/if} class="checkboxx" type="checkbox" value="Revendeur" id="typeagri4" name="typeagri[]"> <span class="revendeur">Revendeur</span>
<input {if $smarty.post.typeagri|stristr:"utre"}checked=checked{/if} class="checkboxx" type="checkbox" value="Autre" id="typeagri5" name="typeagri[]"> <span class="autre">Autre</span>
</div>
</p>
</div>
```

in IdentityController.php :

Before :

```
return $this->customer;
```

Add :

```
$typeagris ='';
        foreach(Tools::getValue('typeagri') as $t) { 

            $typeagris .= $t.','; 

        } 
        $customer->typeagri = $typeagris;
```

If it works, you can now do the same with override (please take a look at http://doc.prestashop.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=51184698 )

Overriding is very important, to not mix native source code and your modifications.

Good luck

Comment: Hello, sorry i let twos values parameters in my HTML code, try to remove value="{if isset($smarty.post.other)}{$smarty.post.other}{/if}"

Comment: like that ?<input class="checkboxx" type="checkbox" value="cerealier" id="typeagri" name="typeagri"> <span class="cerealier">Céréalier</span>

Comment: Ok I still have nothing in my database. It is normal ?

Comment: no that is not normal, try to see if value is well sended, so after $other = Tools::getValue('other'); add var_dump($other);exit;  to see if value is sended before saving it

Comment: add your method processSubmitAccount() from AuthController.php in your post please

Comment: First I add : var_dump($other); exit; Still not working. I just edited my post with the processSubmitAccount() method.

Comment: i didn't see $other = Tools::getValue('other');
$customer->other = $other; in processSUbmitAccount() method, adding var_dump($other);exit; let you see if value is well sended

Comment: My apologize, I put the code in processSubmitLogin(). So I made the modifications, I have only this : string(0) "". So I think, there is another problem. What do you think ?

Comment: it means that you don't get  "other"  value. so at your place i ll comment my html and just let <input type="text" name="other" value="test' > and if the var-dump show "test" on your screen that means the problem is located in your html

Comment: So I tried this : <input class="checkboxx" type="checkbox" value="test" id="typeagri" name="other"> <span class="cerealier">Céréalier</span> and the answer is : string(4) "test". So if I well anderstand, I have a problem with my html code ? I want to save multiple choice in one column, maybe it's not possible exept if I save the result in an array. But I don't know exactly how to do that.

Comment: So, I remove the exit, and now I have something in my database ! Wouhou. But if I check more than one box like crealier and revendeur, I will have only revendeur in my column in my database. Now I thing I need to save the result in an array. Is that possible ?

Comment: yes my example save just one value, if you want save more values you need a loop to get all values : foreach($_POST['other'] as $other) {
        echo $other; 
    }exit;//to see if all values are well sended

Comment: I tried your code, but nothing happend. Maybe I did a mistake. I have no result after the exit. Can you develop a bit more please ?

Comment: it begin to be hard to help you, please put your 3 files on wetransfert, i ll try on my side and then publish my modifications here

Comment: ok i get the files, i ll do it in local, let me some hours ;-p

Comment: I updated my code, so in my DBB, i get values separated by a comma

Comment: Thanks you it works for me to. In the database is it an array of values or just values separate by a comma ?

Comment: it s just values separated by a comma

Comment: $test = '1,2,3';
$test2 = explode(',',$test);           
foreach( $test2 as $t )echo $t."\n"; //example to get value separated with comma

Comment: if it works, please accept my answer, and good luck for your next PS coding challenge

Comment: It works well with my override !!! Thank you so much. Just a last point. I try to do the same thing in identy form. I want to do this modification on this form because my old customers didn't complete this form with the new field. So I try the same modification without result. Any Idea ? Please ? My last demand :p

Comment: for old customer, you need to modify IdentityController.php, please remember to accept my answer above, thanks by advance

Comment: I already try in this file, but without result. I need add the same code like in AuthController.php ?

Comment: Thank you, you are the best ;). I'm waiting

Comment: I updated my post with Identity stuff, code is not very clean but it works on my PS, i also let you an loop to parse the values if you need it in the future

Comment: Thank you very much. It's not working for me. I still have a problem. When I just create an account with 3 boxes checked everything is good in my database. First problem, when I click on "My personnal informations" I have only one box checked and I don't know why ! After, when I tried to modified the identy form, if I check only one box and I save, the database change but remove all the values. Is that normal ?

Comment: send your files please, i ll take a look

Comment: You can dowload it from here : https://wetransfer.com/downloads/6e8f4cf9455ff7d316c0bd9d08247e6220190424084746/107785

Comment: it work if not override, when i use your AuthController.php in override/ , $typeagri still empty, so verify all process without override, and after that do override again  and var_dump($typeagri); step by step to see where it's not working. good luck

Comment: When you modified the identity form is it working ? For me it's still not working :/

Comment: Yes register and identity are working on my local prestashop. vardump() step by step to see when there is an error. you can also try my code on a fresh install PS1.6 you ll see it work.

Comment: The problem is on my identityController.php when I add vardump like that : $typeagris ='';
   foreach(Tools::getValue('typeagri') as $t) { 
    $typeagris .= $t.','; 
    var_dump($typeagri);
    exit;
   } 
   $customer->typeagri = $typeagris;
        return $this->customer; The result at this step is NULL even if I check one or two checkbox.

Comment: are you working in local ? if yes send your project zipped, i ll take a look asap (but i think monday)

Comment: I'm working on a online test prestashop. It's a copy of our website. It's a little bit complicated to give you the project. I will try first on a local prestashop. I did all the modifications following all your steps but I still have a problem with identitu form. It's working with authentication form :)

Comment: I still have no result ... I tried in a new project, same result. I don't know what to do. Thank you for your help.